# Remove CSS class for a specific Div section

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I have code below. From that code, I need to remove the css class on a particular div

```
<div class="testclass">
                    @{
                        IEnumerable<DisplayForm> assignment = val.Items.OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder ?? int.MaxValue);
                        int displayIndex = 0;
                    }
      <div class="ls-propval-list">
                        @foreach (DisplayFormItem displayItem in assignment)
                        {
                            if (displayIndex == 0)
                            {
                                if (displayItem.GetDisplayText(Model.ItemDisplayValue) == val.ItemDisplayName)
                                {
                                    <div class="removeCSSClass">
                                        @displayItem.Render(Model.Value, false, Model.ItemDisplayValue);
                                    </div>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @displayItem.Render(Model.Value, true, Model.ItemDisplayValue);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                
                                    @displayItem.Render(Model.Value, true, Model.ItemDisplayValue);
                                
                            }
                            displayIndex++;
                        }
       </div>
</div>
```

From the above code, I need to remove the "ls-propval-list" css class from the "div class="removeCSSClass"" section. How can I do that?

I tried all the below from document ready jquery, but none of them worked, not sure what wrong I am doing there.

```
                //$("#removeCSSClassdiv").removeClass('ls-propval-list');

                //$("#removeCSSClassdiv").removeAttr("ls-propval-list");

                //$('.removeCSSClassdiv').removeClass('ls-propval-list')

                $('.removeCSSClassdiv .ls-propval-list').removeClass('ls-propval-list');
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. The div with class = "removeCSSClass" does not have the ls-propval-list class, it's parent does. I think what you actually want is to remove from the inner div some styling inherited from the parent div. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, you are correct

Comment: I think then that you will need to separate the styling that you need removed or over-ride the styles with the inner div's class. So for example, if the parent class has font-weight: bold and you want to get rid of that for some inner divs, over-ride the value with font-weight: normal

Comment: <div class="font-weight: normal">
@displayItem.Render(Model.Value, false, Model.ItemDisplayValue);
</div>

Comment: I made the above change. But the text still looks bold

Comment: You need: style=“font-weight: normal”

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.removeCSSClass').parent().removeClass('ls-propval-list');
```

or just this

```
$('.ls-propval-list').removeClass('ls-propval-list');
```

Comment: These two are removing the css class from the remaining div sections as well. But I want that class to be removed only for the div section with class name "removeCSSClass"

Comment: You can edit the answer, Stack Overflow is NOT a forum with threaded discussions

Answer (score 0):

then use this...

```
$('.removeCSSClass').find('.ls-propval-list').removeClass('ls-propval-list');
```

it will remove class from divs inside the div with class=removeCSSClass

this should also work

```
$('.removeCSSClass .ls-propval-list').removeClass('ls-propval-list');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since what you really want is to remove some styling from certain DIVs that are children of the ls-propval-list DIV, you will need to separate those styles. Remember that elements can have more than one class applied. Try splitting the parent's class into the styles you always want and those you don't. or simply over-ride those styles in the specific divs and leave the parent class alone.